# How to use BlowfishPasswordHasher to change password in CakePHP controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

As title, is there anyway that I use BlowFishPasswordHasher in Controller of CakePHP instead of Model (I just use saveField to save new password of user) ?

Comment: you can try this in your controller $oldpwd='123456'; $pass= Security::hash($oldpwd, 'blowfish', true);

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Using 2.x and the shim plugin you can load your hashers using the Factory backport from 3.x: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/2.x/docs/Auth.md#passwordhasherfactory

Comment: Why do you want to move this into the controller at all? I doesn't make sense. http://www.mikebernat.com/images/cake/layercake.png & http://css.dzone.com/news/mvc-fat-models-and-skinny

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling the changing of the password in the model as most likely you are also hashing the password here using beforeSave();

Doing this via a custom validation would be the best method as you can use the correct flow to check if the old password matches the one the user provided. If it does then return true allowing the new password to be hashed using the beforeSave().

For example:

**Model beforeSave()**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

  if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']) && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password']) && strlen($this->data[$this->alias]['password']) > 0) {

    $passwordhash = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordhash->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);

  } 

  return parent::beforeSave();

}
```

Using a custom validation method like:

**Custom Validation**

```
public function oldPassword($password) {

  $user = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $this->data[$this->alias]['username'])));

  $passwordhash = Security::hash($password['oldPassword'], 'blowfish', $user[$this->alias]['password']);

  if ($passwordhash === $user[$this->alias]['password']) {

    return true;

  } else {

    return false;

  }

}
```

Using the above allows you to utilise CakePHP validation to check the old password before allowing the form to submit. If the old password matches the old password from the DB then return true to allow the form to save and the beforeSave to be called which hashes the new password.

Answer (score 0):

here am using $_POST to get fields

```
public function changepassword() {

        if ($this->request->is('post') )
        {
            $pass_stored=0;
            $current_pass= $_POST['new_password'];


           $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
                $newHash = $passwordHasher->hash($current_pass);
          $uid= $_POST['uid'];


            $this->User->query("UPDATE users SET password = '".$newHash."' WHERE id = '".$uid."' ");
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password Saved Sucessfully'), 'success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));    
        }
        else
        {
            $this->set('resettoken', $_REQUEST['id']);  
        }
    }
```